# How to add multiple files to SQL Server using T-SQL and adding one more column

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have two files named A11 and B22. I want to create a third file which merge the records from both of these files with adding one extra column that shows that a records belongs to which original file.

Each files contains three records as following.

A11:

```
Mike,50

Rocky,60

Andy,70
```

B22:

```
Kristen,80

Natasha,90

Mila,100
```

I want output something like this.

Output File

C33:

```
Mike,50,A11

Rocky,60,A11

Andy,70,A11

Kristen,80,B22

Natasha,90,B22

Mila,100,B22
```

Can anyone help me with how to get this desired result?

Comment: When you say file do you actually mean table?

Comment: Yes, Output Table C33.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty sparse on details but I think you can do something like this.

```
insert C33
(
    Name
    , SomeValue
    , SourceFile
)

select Name
    , SomeValue
    , 'A11'
from A11

UNION ALL

select Name
    , SomeValue
    , 'B22'
from B22
```

Comment: This is only sample data. I want to merge more than 50 files and each files have more than 20 columns so can you suggest any option through procedure or something which is automated.

Comment: 50 tables would take about 10-15 minutes. You originally asked this 32 minutes ago. If you just sat down and coded it you would already be done. How do you know which of your 50 tables to use? Doing this dynamically would require dynamic sql. It will most likely take longer to write a dynamic solution than it will to just write this out.

Comment: Or just create 50 insert statements, one for each table.